# A 2D Array of size 8x8, the first column is actually the last column

Tags: javascript, arrays, vector, p5.js

I'm creating a chess game with p5.js library and JavaScript, I've created a 2D Array for the board. The problem is that the second column is the fisrt one, and the fisrt column is the last column.

```js
"use strict";

import * as CONSTANTS from "./constants.js";
import { Tile } from "./Tile.js";

function create2DArray(cols, rows) {
  let array = new Array(cols);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array(rows);
  }
  return array;
}

let gameBoard = create2DArray(CONSTANTS.boardCols, CONSTANTS.boardRows);

const sketch = (p5) => {
  Tile.prototype.draw = function () {
    p5.stroke(0);
    p5.rect(this.position()[0], this.position()[1], this.width, this.width);

    //Va por col*fila
    if (this.absPosition()[0] == 0) {
      p5.fill(50);
    } else {
      p5.fill(255);
    }
  };

  p5.setup = () => {
    p5.createCanvas(CONSTANTS.boardSize, CONSTANTS.boardSize);
    for (let i = 0; i < CONSTANTS.boardCols; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < CONSTANTS.boardRows; j++) {
        gameBoard[j][i] = new Tile(i, j);
      }
    }
  };

  p5.draw = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < CONSTANTS.boardCols; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < CONSTANTS.boardRows; j++) {
        gameBoard[i][j].draw();
      }
    }
  };
};

let board = new p5(sketch, CONSTANTS.chessBoard);
```

I also have other separate files

```
import * as CONSTANTS from "./constants.js";

export class Tile {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = CONSTANTS.tileWidth;
  }

  absPosition() {
    return [this.x, this.y];
  }
  position() {
    return [this.x * this.width, this.y * this.width];
  }
}
```

Separate file for consts:

```
const chessBoard = document.querySelector(".board");
const lightTile = [240, 217, 181];
const darkTile = [181, 136, 99];
const boardSize = 480;
const tileWidth = 60;
const boardRows = boardSize/tileWidth;
const boardCols = boardSize/tileWidth;
    
export { boardSize, chessBoard, lightTile, darkTile, boardRows, boardCols, tileWidth };
```

[image]

As you can see the first column is actually the second one. and the first one Ive made tests and it is the last column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the tiles to the gameBoard array, this should be `gameBoard[i][j] = new Tile(i, j);` instead of `gameBoard[j][i] = new Tile(i, j);`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/K7xc8Vm.png now this is happening.

Comment: You might have to put the if statement in the sketch function before you draw the rectangle.